# Strange 'FileNotFoundError' while running my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a small Hangman game in my free time. The folder contains three files: **main**.py, hangman.py, and words.txt, where hangman.py is a module, and words.txt is a list of words for the game. These files are stored in ~/projects/hangman (I'm running on Ubuntu)

It runs perfectly when I try:

```
aditya@aditya-VirtualBox:~/projects$ cd hangman
aditya@aditya-VirtualBox:~/projects/hangman$ python3 __main__.py
```

However if I try doing this:

```
aditya@aditya-VirtualBox:~/projects$ python3 hangman
```

I end up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "hangman/__main__.py", line 37, in <module>
    while new_game():
  File "hangman/__main__.py", line 21, in new_game
    word = get_word(word_length)
  File "hangman/hangman.py", line 11, in get_word
    with open(filename, 'r') as w:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'
```

In hangman.py, line 11 says:

```py
filename = 'words.txt'
```

Why does running the program in two separate ways give two separate results?

Comment: Your `hangman.py` and `words.txt` files in the same location?

Comment: Why is it strange? It says that it cannot find the file, so give the correct path

Comment: Maybe it is because words.txt is *in* the hangman directory? I thought the python interpreter only looks for files in the directory it was run from, im not too sure though, try using filename = 'hangman.words.txt' or `'hangman/words.txt' `

Comment: @KushanGunasekera Yeah they're stored in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide an absolute path to open() method. Try it like this for python3:

```
import os as o
path = o.path.abspath(o.path.dirname(__file__))
filename = o.path.join(path, "word.txt")
with open(filename, 'r') as w:
        print(w)
```

Comment: In that case, you would get an error when trying to run the file from inside the hangman directory.

Comment: True, I didn't realize that, ty!